# How to loop through a string created by pointer

Tags: c, string, loops, pointers

What I want to do is to iterate through the quote till the end of the quote/(*quote has nothing in it). Is my code valid?

```
char *quote = "To be or not to be, that is the question.";
for (quote = 0; *quote != NULL; quote++){
*quote = tolower(*quote);
}
```

Comment: To cut to the point, `quote = 0` is incorrect.

Comment: Why not use `unsigned int`?

Answer (score 13):

You probably need another pointer to traverse the array, otherwise access to your original string will be lost.

And preferably only use `NULL` for pointers.

Don't use `0` as the initial value, unless you want to use indices instead (see below).

Doing `char *quote =` will simply make `quote` point to the read-only literal, instead of copying the string. Use `char quote[] =` instead.

```
char quote[] = "To be or not to be, that is the question.";
char *quotePtr;
for (quotePtr = quote; *quotePtr != '\0'; quotePtr++){
  *quotePtr = tolower(*quotePtr);
}
```

[Test](http://ideone.com/pXd9r7).

**Using indices:**

```
char quote[] = "To be or not to be, that is the question.";
int i;
for (i = 0; quote[i] != '\0'; i++){
  quote[i] = tolower(quote[i]);
}
```

[Test](http://ideone.com/q7coVT).

Comment: You know that this is most likely to blow up with an access violation due to the string literal being in a readonly page?

Comment: @Dukeling:- doing char *quote="  to be or not ....question"; and taking another char *quotePtr=quote; the same thing can be done .. what's wrong with taking char *quote ="to be or not...question" ...

Comment: @krishnaChandra Any string literal (something in `""`) is read-only. Trying to modify it would result in undefined behaviour - an error can occur, nothing can happen, it can actually modify the string literal or something worse. If you do `char *quote=`, you simply make `quote` point to this read-only string, so the above code would try to modify it. However, if you do `char quote[]=`, this would actually create a copy of the string literal and make `quote` point to the copy, which you are free to modify.

Answer (score 4):

Consider this as an expansion to the answer given by [Dukeling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1711796/dukeling)

When you use

```
char *quote = "Hello World";
```

This makes a read-only string, means that you can't change its contents in a simpler way.

```
Here *quote points to 'H'
BUT, you cannot do *quote = 'A';
This will give you an error.
```

If you wish to make changes to the characters in a string, it is a good habit to use arrays.

```
char quote[] = "Hello World";
Here also *quote points to 'H'
BUT, in this case *quote = 'A' is perfectly valid.
The array quote will get changed.
```

Answer (score 0):

You're reassigning `quote` in your `for` initializer, which is invalid and will cause an access-violation because you're dereferencing it in the `*quote != NULL` part.

Semantically `NULL` and `'\0'` are equivalent, but syntactically I'd prefer this. Note that by using this approach you keep a pointer to (the start of) the string.

```
wchar const_t* quote = L"To be or not to be, that is the question.";

for( wchar_t* c = quote; *c != '\0'; c++ ) {

    *c = tolower( *c );
}
```

alternatively using an index:

```
wchar const_t quote[] = L"To be or not to be, that is the question.";

for( size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(quote); i++ ) {

    quote[i] = tolower( quote[i] );
}
```

(note that the semantics of `sizeof` will change if the value of `quote` is not known at compile time)

Comment: Why is reassigning then dereferencing a pointer invalid? Your code does the same, so presumably your reasons are just incorrect.

Comment: `wchar const_t* quote` is a constant string literal which you cannot modify so your code will fail.